# Android Build issue while creating a new project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, build.gradle

I have been struggling with this gradle for the last one week. None of the earlier questions on gradle issue could solve my problem.

Things I did :

1. Download the latest gradle. I did it by changing the path at distribution URL in gradle-wrappper properties.

(It will download the latest one say 2.14. but, When I create a new project, It will be set to 2.10 and then back to same dirt)

- Should I download the gradle for every project I create ? ... Help me fix this.

Thanks in advance :)

[This is the error when I create a new project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVtq4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version of gradle with in `build.gradle`.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse **gradle** and the **android plugin for gradle**.

1) You can define the gradle distribution used by a project in the file
 `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

For example:

```
  distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14-all.zip
```

Each project can use a different version. You will find the distributions file inside `\user\.gradle\wrapper\dists` folder.

2) Gradle is a build tool, but it requires specific plugin to work.
Android Tool Team is releasing the Android plugin for Gradle.

You can define the plugin inside the `build.gradle` file in the project.

For example:

```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
```

Each project (or module) can use a different version.

Also go to  **File > Settings > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle** 
and set **Use default gradle wrapper**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have installed a latest android studio bundle. Messed up lots of things in the old version. Thanks anyways